# XGBoost - Country Feature should be labeld or one hot encoded?

Tags: model, xgboost, feature-selection

We have a feature of a country in our model, and we are using a label encoder for it, for example:

BEL - 1,
US - 2,
ENG - 3,

etc...

What's the best practice for XGBoost model - use it as a numeric number or perform one hot encoding for that?

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 0):

There is no golden standard.

OHE is safer, since it does not introduce artificial order to the categories. On the down side, it increases memory footprint for features with multiple unique values and trees might srtaggle to find a balance between splits on numerical features and such added hordes of new OHE features. Often (based on kaggle competitions) label encoding performs as good or better than OHE.

Why don't you try both and choose one that gives you better evaluation metric of your choice in cross validation? This way you treat this choice as another type of feature engineering. Note, that you might need to run hyperparameter optimisation for the two scenarious separately, as in some cases parameters like tree depth can be very different.