# Should Nominal Numeric Categories should be OneHotEncoded or left alone (resembling OrdinalEncoding)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I've found a post similar to my question: [XGBoost - Country Feature should be labeld or one hot encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688039/xgboost-country-feature-should-be-labeld-or-one-hot-encoded)

I have 2 columns (colour,dayofweek) which is encoded like 1,2,3,...6,7.

In theory, if I don't OHE it, it would cause the algo to think there is an numeric ranking, eg 1>2>3.  To avoid this, I should OHE.

So I create 2 pipelines with OHE and without running several algo:

```
for k,v in model_dict.items():
    pipeline_dict[k] = Pipeline([('preprocessor',ct['ohe']),('model',v)])

for k,v in model_dict.items():
    pipeline_dict_no_ohe[k] = Pipeline([('model',v)])
```

The results for KNN, Gaussian Naive Bayees, XGB, RandomForest, DecisionTree:

```
    With OHE:knn = 0.73622, gnb = 0.65814, xgb = 0.78996, rf = 0.79015, dt = 0.79041
Without OHE: knn = 0.77133, gnb = 0.70049, xgb = 0.94987, rf = 0.94138, dt = 0.83169
```

Very surprising to me.  Going by the results, I would pick without OHE.  But this sound so wrong as it does not seem to be the right thing to do.

Questions:

1. What is the reason for a better results without OHE ?
2. Does the algo really think there is a ranking to colour & dayofweek ?
3. Would it give problems in the future if the model thinks there is a ranking in the model ?

The reason why I have concern is that recently, in a test, I have corrupted my DataFrame but it gave fantastic result !  That's why I asked to get a better confidence of the model I'm creating.

Thanks very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

The models will think there is an ordering, and even arithmetic relationships (Monday+Wednesday=Thursday, e.g.) with this encoding, unless they are programmed to recognize the integers as being representatives of categories (not the case with any of your sklearn models).  Tree models don't deal with arithmetic at all, only ordering, and sometimes they can perform well even with the artificial ordering imposed; for that, have a search at [datascience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com), e.g. [my answer here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77880/55122) and the Linked questions from there.

Your `dayofweek` actually *is* ordinal, although a cyclic representation might be even better.  `colour` though is almost surely not.

To the questions:

1. It's nearly impossible to say without the data.  Tree models doing better makes some sense to me (not as a rule, but as a possibility), but kNN and GNB are surprising.
2. Yes.
3. If you're properly scoring on unseen test data, this should be fine.  Data drift might cause more issues with this "improper" encoding, but it's really very hard to say.